# Switch Lastname, Firstname to Firstname Lastname inside List

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have two lists of sports players. One is structured simply:

```
['Lastname, Firstname', 'Lastname2, Firstname2'..]
```

The second is a list of lists structured:

```
[['Firstname Lastname', 'Team', 'Position', 'Ranking']...]
```

I ultimately want to search the contents of the second list and pull the info if there is a matching name from the first list.

I need to swap 'Lastname, Firstname' to 'Firstname Lastname' to match list 2's formatting for simplification.

Any help would be great. Thanks!

Comment: I'm not clear- do you want to know how to pull the info from one list based on the other, or just to change the format?

Comment: I just want to change the format to match. Figured it would be simpler to change the format of the first list since its a simple list containing only strings (the name) vs the other list which is a list of lists. Your answer below solved this spot on. Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can swap the order in the list of names with:

```
[" ".join(n.split(", ")[::-1]) for n in namelist]
```

---

An explanation: this is a list comprehension that does something to each item. Here are a few intermediate versions and what they would return:

```
namelist = ["Robinson, David", "Roberts, Tim"]
# split each item into a list, around the commas:
[n.split(", ") for n in namelist]
# [['Robinson', 'David'], ['Roberts', 'Tim']]

# reverse the split up list:
[n.split(", ")[::-1] for n in namelist]
# [['David', 'Robinson'], ['Tim', 'Roberts']]

# join it back together with a space:
[" ".join(n.split(", ")[::-1]) for n in namelist]
# ['David Robinson', 'Tim Roberts']
```

Comment: Awesome! Worked like a charm. Care to briefly explain what is going on? Thanks!

Comment: `n.split(", ")[::-1]` is more clearly written as `reversed(n.split(", "))`

Comment: To make whitespace optional after the commas and allow it before and after the individual words, I'd use `[" ".join(n.replace(","," ").split()[::-1]) for n in namelist]`.