# Python and flipping the order of lastname, firstname

Tags: python, string, split

I have a string such as `smith, bob;jones, bill;doe, john` that is coming from a CSV file.  I would like to extract the names and flip the order of the last name and first name to be first name then last name.

I tried the example shown in [switch-lastname-firstname](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15704943/switch-lastname-firstname-to-firstname-lastname-inside-list) but that example does not work for me.

I also tried:

```
namelist = ['smith, bob;jones, bill;doe, john']
n2=''
for n in namelist:
    name = n.partition(',')
    fn = name[2]
    ln = name[0]
    n2 += fn + ' ' + ln + ';'
```

However - it doesn't separate out the names but Works fine if there is only one name instead of a list of names... What can I do to correct this?

Comment: Your list is not really a list.

Comment: You might want to first sit for a couple of hours and read a basic tutorial, like the one in http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/

Comment: `[]` is a list, and `[1,2,3]` is a list with 3 elements. `'x;y;z'.split(';')` is also a list with 3 elements. BUT `['x;y;z']` is a list with only one element.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Quite simple using the `split` function.

```
s = 'smith, bob;jones, bill;doe, john'
for lname, fname in [q.split(",") for q in s.split(";")]:
    print fname, lname
```

This will output

```
bob smith
bill jones
john doe
```

Answer (score 1):

```
s = 'smith, bob;jones, bill;doe, john'
f = s.split(';')
for ll in f:
   lname, fname = ll.split(',')
   print fname, lname
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a so-called python one liner...

```
s = 'smith, bob;jones, bill;doe, john'

result = ';'.join([("%s, %s" % (fn, ln)) for ln, fn in [tuple(k.split(",")) for k in s.split(";")]]).strip()
```

But, as it seems like you are new to python, here is and step by step explanation...

```
#First, you need to separate the names and create a list of names. This is done by,
listOfNames = s.split(";")

#Then, each item in the name is split into first and last names and a list of tuples is created.
listOfNameTuples = [tuple(name.split(",")) for name in listOfNames]

#Then, the reversed name tuples can be created with this.
listOfNameTuples2 = [(fn, ln) for (ln, fn) in listOfNameTuples]

#Then tuple items are merged to reversed name strings.
listOfNames2 = ["%s, %s" % (fn, ln) for (fn, ln) in listOfNameTuples2]

#Finally, they are joined together, seperated with a ";" and leading and trailing spaces are removed with `.Strip()`
result = ";".join(listOfNames2).strip()
```